# How do I give a php element a css class?

Tags: php, css

Here is the base php item i would like to add the class to:

```
<?php echo $nav_sub; ?>
```

Here is the class that I would like to add to the PHP element:

```
class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"
```

Comment: And what is the output of: `<?php echo $nav_sub; ?> ` ?

Comment: That isn't a PHP element (there is no such thing as a PHP element [at least in the sense that you can style it like a HTML element]). That's some PHP code that (presumably) generates an HTML element.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add to an HTML element?

Comment: Please show where `$nav_sub` is created

Comment: I didn't write the program where it gets the information for the code, but I have just contacted the developers of it so I should have the location soon.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Your question doesn't make sense because CSS classes are applied to a specific piece of HTML DOM. PHP is only outputting the pieces of HTML DOM and therefore you can't apply CSS directly to PHP.

A better question might be: "How do I modify the contents of a PHP variable that contain HTML to append a CSS class?"

(Or potentially, how do I apply a CSS class to a piece of HTML DOM using JavaScript.)

Let's say `$nav_sub` contained a string: `<div>Navigation Item</div>`

and you wanted it to contain: `<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Navigation Item</div>`

You could make this modification several ways. One way might be to replace `<div` with `<div` + your classes.

Specifically,

```
$nav_sub = '<div>Navigation Item</div>';
echo str_replace('<div' , '<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"' , $nav_sub);
```